# rsyslog exclude logs based on hostname

Tags: syslog

We have our rsyslog server set up to forward messages to our Splunk box.  However we want to cut through some of the noise so we have set up specific programs to disregard. So basically if logs are dhcpd, drop.  Forward everything else.

```
if $programname != 'dhcpd' then @@0.0.0.0:514
```

Is there a way to also exclude certain hostnames based on words in those hostnames.  So for example:

```
hostname-ABC1.log <--- exclude
hostname2-ABC1.log <--- exclude
reghostname <---- keep and forward
```

Version 5.8.10

Comment: Which rsyslog version are you using ?

Comment: rsyslog version 5.8.10

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to ingest the logs into Splunk and then have your UniversalFowarder or Indexer drop what you need. It's much easier to adjust this with Splunk then modifying rsyslog. You can do this with props and transforms.

Setup what you need in [props.conf](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.4.2/Admin/Propsconf)
Then the [transforms.conf](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.4.2/Admin/Transformsconf)

What I would do is use regex.

In your props.conf:

```
[source::udp:514]
TRANSFORMS-drop_hosts = drop_ABCHOSTS
```

In your transforms.conf:

```
[drop_ABCHOSTS]
SOURCE_KEY = Metadata:Host
REGEX = ABC1\.log
DEST_KEY = queue
FORMAT = nullQueue
```